# Iphone cannot load heavy data

Tags: jquery, node.js, mongodb, large-data

currently IPhone or Ipad cannot load huge data. But on the desktop and Android phones, everything is working fine.

Below is my specification

- Node JS: v12.22.5
- MongoDB: 3.6.8
- Frontend: HTML5 + CSS + JQuery + datatables plugin
  (https://datatables.net/)

Below is my Schema

```
const adminAuditSchema = mongoose.Schema({
who: {
    type: String,
    //ref: 'Admin'
},
what: {
    type: String
},
when: {
    type: Date
},
who_id: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId
},
who_type: {
    type: String,
    emum: ['Admin', 'Customer']
}
  });
```

Below is how coding in Node JS

```
app.get('/audit-trail', function (req, res) {
    AdminAudit.find(null, 'who what when', { sort: { 'when': 'descending' } }).exec(function (err, docs) {
        res.json(docs)
    });
});
```

**Currently, my Admin audit trail has 120K ++ data in the database. So, how do I load all the data on the Iphone and Ipad?**

Comment: Are you trying to load 120k+ data all at once? If so, I would suggest you to use pagination.

Comment: just wondering why you are not using pagination on your api ?  ifi you have 120K + data on your database, it will increase your bandwidth usage when you request all of the data at the same time.  You can prefer to use pagination for performance solutions

Comment: What are you expecting the user to do with 120k+ on an *iphone*?  This will not be of any use.  Add paging *and* filtering (search) so the user can find what they want.